# Achievements menu gets stuck open, and doesn't respond to input

Tags: bug, android-app

In the new version of the Android app (I'm guessing it was updated recently), the Achievements menu gets stuck open, but doesn't respond to input. Trying to click the X clicks on whatever happens to be in the top right corner under it. Seems to be related to pressing Back on the phone too soon after opening the menu.

The only fix seems to be closing the app.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-N910W8
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (N910W8VLU1DPE2)